# 405 response on POST in VisualStudio 2015 C# WPF From my WS Rest/java

Tags: c#, post, visual-studio-2015, http-status-code-405

in first place sorry if my english is a little poor.
I have a problem with a WebService Maven(java) when i try to send a Json POST to it Visual studio send me an exception "405 method not allowed". When I make test with PostMan or SoapUI it's work fine. In fact the WebService receive a json like this in the followin url:

https://misofertas.azurewebsites.net/GeneraMail/rest/usuario/data/post/

```
{"nombre":"Sergio","apellido":"Vega","email":"mcherniakovsky@gmail.com"}
```

And then the WebService send a e-mail to the destination. How i said, the webservice send the email when i test with SoapUi or PostMan.
In my Visual studio method i have this code:

```
        public void enviarCorreos(List<Correos> listaCorreos)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
        foreach (var item in listaCorreos)
        {

            Uri siteuri = new Uri("https://misofertas.azurewebsites.net/GeneraMail/rest/usuario/data");
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(siteuri);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "(Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1(java 1.5)";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    nombre = item.nombre.ToString(),
                    apellido = item.apellido.ToString(),
                    correo = item.correo.ToString()
                });

                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }


            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8, true))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

    }
```

My visual studio versión is 2015 and work with the framework 4.5
thanks!

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of your Postman request ?

Comment: here is the screenshot from the post man with the reply https://prntscr.com/lhynef

Comment: In your c# code you have a property called `correo` that doesn’t exist in the Json...

Comment: that it's true but i made the change an nothing happen still the 405 response ;´(

Comment: @AndrésCasas-Cordero Are you sure that you're calling the web service with the correct URL? The Postman URL is "https://misofertas.azurewebsites.net/GeneraMail/rest/usuario/data/post/", but the link in C# code is "https://misofertas.azurewebsites.net/GeneraMail/rest/usuario/data".

Comment: Ups! I loose a lot of time because that. Now it's working. Sorry guys for my newbie error, and thanks for your help!